# Proof verification: To show that a function is not Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I would like to verify my solution for the following problem:

Let $g:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a nonzero, continuous function and define $G:[0,1]\times[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$G(x,y)=g(xy).$$
Show that $G$ is not in $L^1([0,1]\times[1,\infty))$.

Solution:

$$\int_1^\infty \int_0^1|G(x,y)|dx dy = \int_1^\infty \int_0^1|g(xy)|dx dy = \int_1^\infty \int_0^y\cfrac{|g(t)|}{y}dt dy \geq \int_1^\infty \cfrac{1}{y} \inf_{t\in(0,y]} |g(t)|\; dy \geq \inf_{t\in(0,\infty)} |g(t)|\int_1^\infty \cfrac{1}{y} dy = \infty$$

I'm a little concerned about taking the infimum over the non compact set $(0,y]$ ($g$ is not defined at $0$).

Is this correct? And if so, how do I address my concern above? Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is wrong precisely for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. How do I remedy this? The problem is typed out exactly as it appeared on an exam. Should $g$ be defined on $[0,\infty)$ instead?

Comment: Try Tonelli's theorem (for $t$ and $y$) rather than the first inequality you wrote down.

Comment: Observe that if $y$ is large enough you can find an interval $(a,b)\subset (0,y)$ where $|g(t)|\ge \varepsilon>0$ By continuity. I think that would make your argument work.

Comment: Thanks. I find it odd that the function $g$ is not defined at $0$ but $G$ is. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $T$ such that $\int_0^{T}|g(t)|dt >0$. Note that $\int_1^{\infty}\int_0^{y} \frac {|g(t)|} y dt dy \geq \int_T^{\infty}\int_0^{y} \frac {|g(t)|} y dt dy$. Now use the fact that $\int_0^{y}|g(t)|dt \geq \int_0^{T}|g(t)|dt$ for $y >T$. Can you finish?